# How to include the grid layout in angular material design?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am trying to make a grid layout in Angular Material. I followed their documentation and some of my CSS is working fine, like `button` and `input`, but grid is not rendering any CSS. It is just rendering the simple HTML.

**Source I followed:**

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options

**CSS:**

```
<!-- STYLES -->
    <!-- build:css lib/css/main.min.css -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/angular-material/angular-material.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="components/angular-material/modules/css/angular-material-layouts.css"> 
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

**module.js**

```
var app = angular.module('PdbTool', ["ng","ngAnimate","ngAria",'ngMdIcons','ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource','ngRoute', 'satellizer', 'myConfig.config'])
  .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
    .primaryPalette('pink')
    .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

**scripts**

```
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- build:js lib/js/main.min.js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/satellizer/satellizer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- Custom Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dashboard.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/configFileLocal.js"></script>
    <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="js/configFileProd.js"></script-->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular-material-icons/0.4.0/angular-material-icons.min.js"></script>
```

**html code:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div layout="row" layout-sm="column"> 
    <div flex>
      I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
    </div>
    <div flex>
      I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
    </div>
  </div>
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Search</label>
        <input ng-model="search">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here, made a simple codepen and it seems to work fine.  The two flex divs are side by side until you shrink the window, then they stack: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meXwzx

Comment: How does it getting the padding and height all those things, do we have to customize eveything, I have worked in bootstrap and things goes easy with class inclusion of row and column, now getting how o include in MD

Comment: If i need to include this search box at centre of the page with a header bar  fixed at top in the dark blue theme :
say a google search page.
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" >
      <div layout="row" style="background-color:#027cd5"> 
        <div flex>
            <md-input-container ng-style='pos' ng-click="firstLinkClick()">
              <label>Search</label>
              <input ng-model="search">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ui-view></div>
    <div> how should I approach

Answer (score 0):

i dont use material desing so i wrote my own directives for css grid layout. like this;

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[v-grid]"
})
export class GridDirective {
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-columns")
  @Input() columns: string;
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-rows")
  @Input() rows: string;
  @HostBinding("style.grid-template-areas")
  @Input() areas: string;

  constructor(private readonly el: ElementRef, private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "display", "grid");
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: "[v-grid-area]"
})
export class GridAreaDirective {
  @HostBinding("style.grid-area")
  @Input("v-grid-area") area: string;
}
```

and i used like this;

```
<div v-grid columns="1fr 100px" rows="1fr 1fr" areas="'area1 area2' 'area1 area2'">
   <div v-grid-area="area1" style="background-color: red">
      <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
   </div>
   <div v-grid-area="area2" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
</div>
```

maybe this answer will be helpful for you.